# Use cucumber to interact with sub cucumber tests

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs, test-framework

We have a situation where we have several products (**frontend, app, api**) and each of them is tested already using cucumber.
Now we would like to test all the product together re-using the test already written, so basically we want to do an action on **frontend** followed by one in **app**

```
When I create a user X,Y in frontend
Then I login with the user X,Y in the app
```

in the respective subproject the steps are already defined and working, but we want another level of abstraction, is this possible we cucumber or any other test framework or we have to write our own implementation?

Comment: FYI. Step method can be called from another step method.

Comment: it is advised to not do, and even not allowed for cucumberjs

Comment: Why not put those steps into your page object model as functions and call them as the only thing inside of your step definition?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scenario: Register in front end, login via app
  Given I registered in the front end
  When I login via the app
  Then I should be logged into the app
```